# Origin incorrect redirection in koajs

Tags: node.js, iis, koa

I have an endpoint at `my.origin1/myendpoint` that redirects to another endpoint:

```
router.get('/myendpoint', {
  var param = this.query.myParam;
  this.redirect(`http://my.origin2/myotherendpoint?param=${param}`);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.request.header,undefined,2));
})
```

the console log output shows:

```
{
  "location": "http://my.origin2/myotherendpoint?param=myParamValue",
  "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  "content-length": "whatever"
}
```

However, the redirect request gets a 404 and when I observe it in fiddler I see the location header with `my.origin1/myotherendpoint?param=myParamValue`. What could be causing this?

I have trawled through the code and there aren't any middlewares intercepting the request, I have also checked our IIS settings and there are no url redirects that could be effecting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

IIS needed to have the proxy setting `reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders` set to `false`